# Fine positionning slider thumb

Tags: c#, wpf

I know this is not the best UX possible but still, I wish to achieve this :

Anytime `shift` is pressed, I'd like my `usercontrol` (basically a slider) to have its `Thumb` (and so its `Value`) to move twice slower as it should normally.

This is what I have so far.

```
public partial class CustomSlider : UserControl
{
    public CustomSlider()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        CMiXSlider.ApplyTemplate();
        Thumb thumb0 = (CMiXSlider.Template.FindName("PART_Track", CMiXSlider) as Track).Thumb;
        thumb0.MouseEnter += new MouseEventHandler(thumb_MouseEnter);

    }

    private void thumb_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed && e.MouseDevice.Captured == null)
        {
            MouseButtonEventArgs args = new MouseButtonEventArgs(e.MouseDevice, e.Timestamp, MouseButton.Left);
            args.RoutedEvent =  MouseLeftButtonDownEvent;
            (sender as Thumb).RaiseEvent(args);
        }
    }

    Point pStart;
    Point pCurrent;
    Point pCenter;
    bool isDragging;

    private void CMiXSlider_DragStarted(object sender, DragStartedEventArgs e)
    {
        isDragging = true;
        if (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.LeftShift))
        {
            pStart = Mouse.GetPosition(CMiXSlider);
        }
    }

    private void CMiXSlider_DragDelta(object sender, DragDeltaEventArgs e)
    {
        pCurrent = Mouse.GetPosition(CMiXSlider);
        if (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.LeftShift) == true )
        {
            pCenter.X = Math.Abs(pCurrent.X - pStart.X);
            pCenter.Y = Math.Abs(pCurrent.Y - pStart.Y);
            Value = (1.0 / CMiXSlider.ActualWidth) * pCenter.X/2 + (1.0 / CMiXSlider.ActualWidth)*pStart.X;
            if (Value >= 1.0)
            {
                Value = 1.0;
            }
            else if (Value <= 0.0)
            {
                Value = 0.0;
            }
        }
    }

    private void CMiXSlider_DragCompleted(object sender, DragCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        isDragging = false;
    }

    private void CMiXSlider_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {

        if (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.LeftShift) && isDragging == true)
        {
            pStart = Mouse.GetPosition(CMiXSlider);
        }
    }
```

And the XAML :

```
<UserControl x:Class="CMiX.CustomSlider"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CMiX"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="116.3" d:DesignWidth="567.2">
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/CMiX_UserControl;component/RessourceDictionnaries/Brushes/GenericBrushes.xaml"/>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/CMiX_UserControl;component/RessourceDictionnaries/Styles/BaseSliderStyle.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>
<Slider x:Name="CMiXSlider" Style="{StaticResource BaseSliderStyle}" Margin="1"
        Thumb.DragDelta="CMiXSlider_DragDelta"
        Thumb.DragStarted="CMiXSlider_DragStarted"
            Orientation="{Binding Orientation, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:CustomSlider}}}" 
            Value="{Binding Value, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:CustomSlider}}}" 
            IsMoveToPointEnabled="False" Minimum="0.0" Maximum="1.0" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"/>
```

Few problems though. Now I must press `Shift` first and then drag, otherwise if I first start to drag and then shift, the thumb jump backward.

I'm missing some logic somewhere.

Any advice ?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you could do, is process the changes to `Value` every single iteration so you can handle the current "speed" of the drag.

For this example I'm assuming you have the DependencyProperties `Minimum`, `Maximum` and `Value` like any Control based on `RangeBase` (`Slider`, `ProgressBar`, etc.).

<sub>A lot of variables in this example are unneccessary and only serve to demonstrate the steps in the calculation</sub>

```
private void CMiXSlider_OnDragStarted(object sender, DragStartedEventArgs e)
{
    _lastPos = GetMousePosition();
}

private double GetMousePosition()
{
    return Mouse.GetPosition(this).X;
}

private void CMiXSlider_OnDragDelta(object sender, DragDeltaEventArgs e)
{
    double thumbPosition = GetMousePosition();
    double deltaX = thumbPosition - _lastPos;
    _lastPos = thumbPosition;

    if (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.LeftShift))
        deltaX /= 2;

    double effectiveLength = ActualWidth - CMiXSlider.ActualWidth;
    double effectiveChange = deltaX / effectiveLength;
    double valueRange = Maximum - Minimum;

    Value = Math.Min(Maximum, Math.Max(Minimum, Value + effectiveChange * valueRange));

    RepositionThumb();
}

private void RepositionThumb()
{
    double relativePosition = (Value - Minimum) / (Maximum - Minimum);
    double absolutePosition = (ActualWidth - CMiXSlider.ActualWidth) * relativePosition;
    CMiXSlider.Margin = new Thickness(absolutePosition,0,0,0);
}
```

Should look something like this:

[image: Thumb Animation]

Alternatively (if this is not "precise" enough) you could process the changes based on the last position where the state of <kbd>Shift</kbd> was changed.

Complete Code for reference:

## C#:

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Controls.Primitives;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace ShiftSlider
{
    public partial class CustomSlider : UserControl
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty MinimumProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
            "Minimum", typeof(double), typeof(CustomSlider), new PropertyMetadata((double)0.0));

        public double Minimum
        {
            get { return (double) GetValue(MinimumProperty); }
            set { SetValue(MinimumProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty MaximumProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
            "Maximum", typeof(double), typeof(CustomSlider), new PropertyMetadata((double)100.0));

        public double Maximum
        {
            get { return (double) GetValue(MaximumProperty); }
            set { SetValue(MaximumProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty ValueProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
            "Value", typeof(double), typeof(CustomSlider), new PropertyMetadata(default(double)));

        private double _lastPos;

        public double Value
        {
            get { return (double) GetValue(ValueProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ValueProperty, value); }
        }

        public CustomSlider()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void CMiXSlider_OnDragStarted(object sender, DragStartedEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
            _lastPos = GetMousePosition();
        }

        private double GetMousePosition()
        {
            return Mouse.GetPosition(this).X;
        }

        private void CMiXSlider_OnDragDelta(object sender, DragDeltaEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
            double thumbPosition = GetMousePosition();
            double deltaX = thumbPosition - _lastPos;
            _lastPos = thumbPosition;

            if (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.LeftShift))
                deltaX /= 2;

            double effectiveLength = ActualWidth - CMiXSlider.ActualWidth;
            double effectiveChange = deltaX / effectiveLength;
            double valueRange = Maximum - Minimum;

            Value = Math.Min(Maximum, Math.Max(Minimum, Value + effectiveChange * valueRange));

            RepositionThumb();
        }

        private void RepositionThumb()
        {
            double relativePosition = (Value - Minimum) / (Maximum - Minimum);
            double absolutePosition = (ActualWidth - CMiXSlider.ActualWidth) * relativePosition;
            CMiXSlider.Margin = new Thickness(absolutePosition,0,0,0);
        }

        private void CMiXSlider_OnDragCompleted(object sender, DragCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            // 
        }
    }
}
```

## XAML:

```xml
<UserControl x:Class="ShiftSlider.CustomSlider"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignWidth="300" d:DesignHeight="20">
    <Grid>
        <Rectangle Fill="LightGray" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
        <Thumb VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="20" Name="CMiXSlider" 
               DragStarted="CMiXSlider_OnDragStarted" DragDelta="CMiXSlider_OnDragDelta" 
               DragCompleted="CMiXSlider_OnDragCompleted"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

## Update for you Control

```
private void thumb_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    /*if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed && e.MouseDevice.Captured == null)
    {
        MouseButtonEventArgs args = new MouseButtonEventArgs(e.MouseDevice, e.Timestamp, MouseButton.Left);
        args.RoutedEvent = MouseLeftButtonDownEvent;
        (sender as Thumb).RaiseEvent(args);
    }*/
}

Point pStart;
bool isDragging;
private bool shiftDown;
private double startValue;

private void CMiXSlider_DragStarted(object sender, DragStartedEventArgs e)
{
    isDragging = true;
    pStart = Mouse.GetPosition(CMiXSlider);
    shiftDown = Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.LeftShift);
    startValue = Value;
}

private void CMiXSlider_DragDelta(object sender, DragDeltaEventArgs e)
{
    bool newShiftDown = Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.LeftShift);

    double scale = newShiftDown ? 0.5 : 1;

    Point pCurrent = Mouse.GetPosition(CMiXSlider);

    if (newShiftDown != shiftDown)
    {
        shiftDown = newShiftDown;
        pStart = pCurrent;
        startValue = Value;
    }

    Point pDelta = new Point(pCurrent.X - pStart.X, pCurrent.Y - pStart.Y);

    Value = startValue + (pDelta.X / CMiXSlider.ActualWidth) * scale;

    if (Value >= 1.0)
    {
        Value = 1.0;
    }
    else if (Value <= 0.0)
    {
        Value = 0.0;
    }
}

private void CMiXSlider_DragCompleted(object sender, DragCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    isDragging = false;
}

private void CMiXSlider_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{

    /*if (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.LeftShift) && isDragging == true)
    {
        pStart = Mouse.GetPosition(CMiXSlider);
    }*/
}
```

Comment: hi, just find out that `ActualWidth` is the same as `CMiXSlider.ActualWidth` so effectiveChange is infinite or NaN.

Comment: @lecloneur I used `CMiXSlider` as the `Thumb`, so in your case you'll probably need to use `thumb0.ActualWidth` instead. If there are any further issues please post the complete code (including XAML).

Comment: just added the XAML

Comment: @lecloneur I'm afraid the way you are doing it now is a bit different from what I proposed. I added my complete code for reference while I try to make your work.

Comment: well thins is, your example is working but I don't see how I can access the thumb in my case.

Comment: The problem (the "jumping" of the Thumb of the Slider when pressing / releasing Shift) is that the Slider control is handling the value changes and position changes of the Thumb aswell. You are basically in a constant fight with the Slider control over who controls the value. You could change the Value Binding to OneWay to circumvent this but then the it would constantly "jump" around very visibly (I've added the modified code so you can see for yourself - maybe you can harvest some ideas behind it.

Comment: My recommendation: write you own control that supports this modification or modify the [Reference Implementation](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/Framework/System/Windows/Controls/Slider.cs,6532ecbe410bb4ae).

Comment: Yes, I also find out that having both Thumb going to mouse position when clicking the slider and slowing down the slider at the same time is not easy to implement.